# Looking for a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty} (\mathbb{R})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm looking for a  $ f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty} (\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x) = 1$ if $x \geq1$, $f(x) =-1$ if $x\leq -1$ and $f'(x) >0$ if $-1<x<1$. I found this function
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } 1 \leq x \\
1- e^{\frac{-2x}{1-x}} &\text{if } 0 \leq x <1 \\
e^{\frac{2x}{x+1}} -1  &\text{if } -1 \leq x <0 \\
-1 &\text{if } x \leq -1
\end{cases} $$

Anyone has a simple function? Any idea?

Comment: hmm, your example doesn't seem smooth at $x=0$

Comment: I'm not seeing this. Why does you say that?

Comment: The two functions are analytic at $0$, yet they are not th esame functions, so their Taylor series must be different

Comment: Your construction below really works and it is less complicated. But the function that I looking , not need be analytic, only need be infinitely differentiable. Is the function that I found infinitely differentiable?

Comment: By the way, thank you for help me.

Comment: modulo my mistakes, if the two Taylor series are different say at $x^n$ then your $f$ shouldn't have $n$-th derivative at $x=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two standard ideas. Let $g(x)=e^{-1/x}$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x\leq0$. Let $h(x)=g(x)g(1-x)$ (a "bump" function), and let $H$ be the primitive function of $h$ s.t. $H(x)=0$ for $x<0$. then $H(x)=cst$ for $x>1$ and has positive derivative in between.

The other construction is $f(x)=g(x)/(g(x)+g(1-x))$, where again $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x>1$. Modify to so that it suits your needs.